# Unable to programmatically close the application when validation error is found - edited

Tags: delphi

Based on the input from @David, I have edited my post to include more code (the Main procedure and two functions).  The problem remains the same:

I want to check if an array of values contains any alpha characters (which would be invalid), and so I pass the values to a function `CheckForAlphaInArray` from another function called `GetYValues`.  If `CheckForAlphaInArray` finds an alpha character, I want to alert the user to the invalid character, abort and finally terminate the application so that he can correct the error.  The following code does all of it except that it does not close the application.  Instead, it moves to the next line in the code. Why is it not closing?  I tried using `Close` and `frmMain.Close` as well.  Did not work.

Thanks.

```
procedure TfrmMain.actRunExecute(Sender: TObject);
//Run the program using the user-input options in the Analysis Options form
var
  I, K, NumValues, PercentResponse, ConfPercent, PredPercent: integer;
  Header, EstimatedValues, CIHeader_L, CIHeader_U,
  PIHeader_L, PIHeader_U: string;
  C: char;
  EC, HS, SumSqDevX, SumSqDevY, SumCrossProds,
        SumSqDev_YX, MnSumSqDev_YX,
        InputConsMinValue,
        InputConsMaxValue: double;
  InputFile: TStringList;
  X_Array, Y_Array, YHat_Array, SqDevX_Array, SqDevY_Array,
        CrossProds_Array, SD_YX_Array, CILL_Array,
        CIUL_Array, SENewY_Array, PILL_Array, PIUL_Array: TVal_Array;
  MyFile: TextFile;
  const Letters = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z', ',', ' '];
  const Numeric = ['0'..'9', ',', ' '];

begin
  ProgressLabel.Caption := '';

  if not (FormSaved = 'Form Saved') then //if user has saved options form
    MessageDlgPos('Please enter and save analysis options first.',
        mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300)
  else
  begin
       Memo1.Clear;
       Gauge1.Progress := 0;
       InputFile := TStringList.Create;
       OutputFile := TStringList.Create;;
       try
     InputFile.LoadFromFile(OpenDialog1.FileName);
    {if data contains a header row, K = 1, else K = 0  }
     //initialize K to an absurd number
     K := 9999;
     Header := InputFile[0];
     for I := 1 to Length(Header) do
       begin
         C := Header[I];
         if CharInSet(C, Letters) then K := 1
         else if CharInSet(C, Numeric) then K := 0;
       end;

     //call error if K has not changed to either 0 or 1
     if (K = 9999) then
       MessageDlgPos('There is an illegal character in the first' +
               'row of your data.  Please fix it.', mtError,
               [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);

     //initialize X and Y arrays
     SetLength(X_Array, InputFile.Count - K);
     SetLength(Y_Array, InputFile.Count - K);

      //Get X and Y values
     X_Array := GetXValues(K, InputFile);
     Gauge1.Progress := 10;
     Y_Array := GetYValues(K, InputFile);
     if (AlphaCharFlag = False) then//from GetYValues function
       begin
         Dialogs.MessageDlg('Exiting the application.', mtInformation,
            [mbOk], 0, mbOk);
         Close;
         Exit;
       end;
     NumValues := Length(X_Array);
     Gauge1.Progress := 20;

     //obtain min and max values for constraints in equation
     InputConsMinValue := -1;
     InputConsMaxValue := -1;
     if (ConstraintsYesNo = 'No') then//from analysis options unit
       begin
         InputConsMinValue := InputConstraintMinValue; //from other unit
         InputConsMaxValue := InputConstraintMaxValue; //from other unit
       end
     else if (ConstraintsYesNo = 'Yes') then
       begin
         InputConsMinValue := MinValue(Y_Array);
         InputConsMaxValue := MaxValue(Y_Array);
       end;


     //obtain iteration range for EC
     EC_Low := -1;
     EC_High := -1;
     if (ECRangeFromData = 'No') then//from analysis options unit
       begin
         EC_Low := IterationRangeMinValue; //from other unit
         EC_High := IterationRangeMaxValue; //from other unit
       end
     else if (ECRangeFromData = 'Yes') then
       begin
         EC_Low := MinValue(X_Array);
         EC_High := MaxValue(X_Array);
       end;

     {Obtain the estimated values of EC and HS as a
      single comma-delimited string }
     EstimatedValues := Estimate(NumValues, InputConsMinValue,
                     InputConsMaxValue, EC_Low, EC_High,
                     X_Array, Y_Array);
     Gauge1.Progress := 50;

     {get the two parameters from the comma delimited string
      result of the Estimate function }
     EC := GetFirstValue(EstimatedValues);
     HS := GetSecondValue(EstimatedValues);
     Gauge1.Progress := 90;

     //Obtain y-hat values
     SetLength(YHat_Array, NumValues);
     YHat_Array := Regress(NumValues, K, X_Array, EC, HS);


     //compute array of SumSq dev from mean for X and Y
     SetLength(SqDevX_Array, NumValues);
     SqDevX_Array := GetSqDevVals(NumValues, X_Array);
     SumSqDevX := Sum(SqDevX_Array);
     SetLength(SqDevY_Array, NumValues);
     SqDevY_Array := GetSqDevVals(NumValues, Y_Array);
     SumSqDevY := Sum(SqDevY_Array);

     //Compute array of sum of products
     SetLength(CrossProds_Array, NumValues);
     CrossProds_Array := GetCrossProds(NumValues, X_Array, Y_Array);
     SumCrossProds := Sum(CrossProds_Array);

     //Compute SumSqDev_YX or Sum(d2_YX) in S&C
     SumSqDev_YX := SumSqDevY - Power(SumCrossProds, 2)/SumSqDevX;

     //Compute Mean SumSqDev_YX (s2_YX in S&C)
     MnSumSqDev_YX := SumSqDev_YX/(NumValues - 2);

     //Compute ResMnSq of predicted population regr line
     SetLength(SD_YX_Array, NumValues);
     SD_YX_Array := GetSD_YX(NumValues, MnSumSqDev_YX,
                  SumSqDevX, SqDevX_Array);

     //Get Confidence Limits
     SetLength(CILL_Array, NumValues);
     CILL_Array := GetConfLL(NumValues, CIPercent, 
                 YHat_Array, SD_YX_Array);
     SetLength(CIUL_Array, NumValues);
     CIUL_Array := GetConfUL(NumValues, CIPercent, 
                 YHat_Array, SD_YX_Array);

     //Compute SE of new Y value
     SetLength(SENewY_Array, NumValues);
     SENewY_Array := GetSENewY(NumValues, MnSumSqDev_YX,
                    SumSqDevX, SqDevX_Array);

     //Get Prediction Limits
     SetLength(PILL_Array, NumValues);
     PILL_Array := GetPredLL(NumValues, PIPercent, 
                 YHat_Array, SENewY_Array);
     SetLength(PIUL_Array, NumValues);
     PIUL_Array := GetPredUL(NumValues, PIPercent, 
                 YHat_Array, SENewY_Array);
     Gauge1.Progress := 100;

     //write output file
     OutputFile.Add('EC = ' + FloatToStr(EC));
     OutputFile.Add('HS = ' + FloatToStr(HS));
     OutputFile.Add('');
     //change headers for CI and PI depending on percent chosen by user
     CIHeader_L := '';
     CIHeader_U := '';
     PIheader_L := '';
     PIheader_U := '';
     if (CIPercent = 90) then
       begin
         CIHeader_L := '90% CI_LL';
         CIHeader_U := '90% CI_UL'
       end
     else if (CIPercent = 95) then
       begin
         CIHeader_L := '95% CI_LL';
         CIHeader_U := '95% CI_UL'
       end
     else if (CIPercent = 99) then
       begin
         CIHeader_L := '99% CI_LL';
         CIHeader_U := '99% CI_UL'
       end;


     if (PIPercent = 90) then
       begin
         PIHeader_L := '90% PI_LL';
         PIHeader_U := '90% PI_UL'
       end
     else if (PIPercent = 95) then
       begin
         PIHeader_L := '95% PI_LL';
         PIHeader_U := '95% PI_UL'
       end
     else if (PIPercent = 99) then
       begin
         PIHeader_L := '99% PI_LL';
         PIHeader_U := '99% PI_UL'
       end;

     OutputFile.Add('X ' + ', ' + 'Y ' + ', ' + 'Y-Hat ' + ', ' +
            CIHeader_L + ', ' + CIHeader_U + ', ' +
            PIHeader_L + ', ' + PIHeader_U);
     for I := 0 to NumValues - 1 do
       OutputFile.Add(FloatToStr(X_Array[I]) + ', ' +
               FloatToStr(Y_Array[I]) + ', ' +
               FloatToStr(YHat_Array[I]) + ', ' +
               FloatToStr(CILL_Array[I])  + ', ' +
               FloatToStr(CIUL_Array[I]) + ', ' +
               FloatToStr(PILL_Array[I]) + ', ' +
               FloatToStr(PIUL_Array[I]));

     //display results in Memo field
     Memo1.Clear;
     Application.ProcessMessages;
     for I := 0 to OutputFile.Count - 1 do
        Memo1.Lines.Add(OutputFile[I]);
     mmuFileSave.Enabled := True;
      finally
    InputFile.Free;
    MessageDlgPos('Done!', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
      end;
   end;
end;






//Get Y values in the form of an array
function TfrmMain.GetYValues(K: integer;
  InputFile: TStringList): TVal_Array;
var
  I,J, Posit: integer;
  RowData, Y_Str: string;
  Y_Array: TVal_Array;
  ValidData: Boolean;
  const Letters = ['A'..'Z', 'a'..'z'];
begin
  AlphaCharFlag := True;
  try
    SetLength(Y_Array, InputFile.Count - K);
    try
      //value of K depends on presence/abssence of headers in input file
      for I := K to InputFile.Count-1 do
      begin
    RowData := Trim(InputFile[I]);
    Posit := Pos(',', RowData) - 1;//excluding the comma
    Y_Str := '';
    for J := (Posit+2) to Length(RowData) do Y_Str := Y_Str + RowData[J];
    Y_Str := Trim(Y_Str);
    //check if there are any non-numerical data (letters) in the values
    if not (CheckForAlphaInArray(I, Y_Str)) then
       begin
         AlphaCharFlag := False;
         Exit;
       end;
//        CheckForAlphaInArray(I, Y_Str);
    if (K = 0) then //that is, no header

      begin
        if not TryStrToFloat(Y_Str, Y_Array[I]) then Exit;

      end
    else if (K = 1) then
      begin
        if not TryStrToFloat(Y_Str, Y_Array[I-1]) then Exit;
      end;
      end;
      Result := Y_Array;
      except
    on E: Exception do
       MessageDlgPos('An unexpected error occurred while ' +
              'extracting the Y values from the file. ' +
         E.message, mtError, [mbOK], 0, 300, 300);
      end;
  finally
    Y_Array := nil;
  end;
end;








function TfrmHillSlopeRegr.CheckForAlphaInArray(I: integer; S: string): boolean;
var
  J: integer;
  Chr: char;
  const Numeric = ['0'..'9', '.'];
begin
  for J := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin
    Chr := S[J];
   //if Chr in Numeric then continue else
    if CharInSet(Chr, Numeric) then continue else
    begin
      MessageDlg('Error!  Your file has non-numerical data in row #' +
        IntToStr(I) + '!', mtError, [mbAbort], 0, mbAbort);
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
   end;
   Result := True;
end;
```

Interestingly, it works fine in the case of a stand-alone application with the following code (that I got from Delphi documentation):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Dialogs.MessageDlg('Welcome to my Delphi application.  Exit now?',
    mtConfirmation, [mbYes, mbNo], 0, mbYes) = mrYes then
  begin
    Dialogs.MessageDlg('Exiting the Delphi application.', mtInformation,
      [mbOk], 0, mbOk);
    Close;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Call 'Exit' after you call Application.Terminate.

Comment: Tried that.  It exited the function and then went to the next line in the main procedure that called 'GetYCValues`.

Comment: Well, what did you expect? Exit from there too.

Comment: Exiting from that procedure will not close the application, though.

Comment: You would have had an instant answer if you had made an SSCCE. The problem is trivial to solve for us, if we can see all of the code. The fact that you still don't have a solution is entirely on you. Produce an SSCCE.

Comment: @David, I really thought the code I had up earlier was enough.  I have now include the procedure that call the function too.  Thank you.

Comment: Turned out to be a simple fix - use Abort instead of Exit. Thanks to @MarcusAdams

Comment: Yes, I thought of that too. But I could not really tell what the problem was. You really need to learn how to write an SSCCE. A **short** repro.

Comment: @David: Would you not consider my code above an SSCCE?  If not, would you provide me an example, please, so I can ask a question better the next time? Thanks.

Comment: An SSCCE is as short as possible. It is also complete. It is self-contained. It is compilable. The code here fails on all counts.

Answer (score 3):

`Application.Terminate` simply signals the application to start terminating. It doesn't immediately stop the application.

If you want to stop processing the code in your method, just `Exit;` after calling `Application.Terminate;` (I've cleaned up the code slightly to remove the unnecessary `ValidData` variable):

```
if not (CheckForAlphaInArray(I, Y_Str)) then
begin
  MessageDlg('Exiting the application.', mtInformation, [mbOk], 0, mbOk);
  Application.Terminate;
  Exit;
end;
```

Comment: I just tried this.  It exits the function and simply moves to the next line in the procedure that called the function.  I wonder what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I can't answer that, because I can't see what "the procedure that called the function" is doing. :-) The only way to exit immediately is to call `System.Halt`, which will forcibly end the application (like killing it via Task Manager); this is a bad idea, because it won't allow any cleanup (closing file handles, freeing resources, saving user data, etc.). That's rarely the proper solution; the proper fix is to change your logic to just tell the user **they** need to exit your app, fix the data, and start over instead of trying to force it upon them. Your app should just not process the data.

Comment: I agree. BTW, my last comment was rather rhetorical.  However, the only two pieces of code relevant to this problem are given. The procedure (Main) that called `GetYValues` does not enter the picture in the error handling. It feeds `GetYValues` an array, which in turn passes one value at a time to `CheckForAlphaInArray`. Upon  finding an alpha character, it alerts the user and returns False. If False, `GetYValues` then alerts the user that it is going to close the application, and upon pressing the `OK` button, it should close.  Instead it is exiting `GetYValues` and returning to Main.

Comment: So change whatever code is returning to `Main` to a function that returns a Boolean (or just set a Boolean flag) to indicate whether `Main` can continue, and exit `Main` if that flag is false when the function or procedure returns. Force-closing the application is really user-unfriendly; it's much better, IMO, to show that there's an error and simply not allow continuing until it's fixed. The user could then Alt-Tab to whatever they need to fix the data (or use the menu item in your app that allows it), fix it, and then Alt-Tab back to your app to try again, which is much nicer to me. :-)

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do.  So now, I flagged a False if an alpha was found, and in `Main` if the flag was False, I put an `Exit` there.  No go.  Tried `Close`. Not that either.

Comment: Try `Abort` instead of `Exit`. It escapes the whole execution path, like a silent exception.

Comment: Finally!  This worked.  Thank you @Marcus.  I had based my code on the "official" example from the Delphi website (see my last code above).  Wonder why that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
Application.ShowMainForm := false;
```

right above the terminate command

Comment: Just tried it.  Did not work.  Went to the next line in the code

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question asked (not downvoting, but you should read the question again). This wouldn't stop further code from executing; it would just hide the main form while doing so, which is not the same thing at all.

Comment: I did read the question, this is how I did it in the past with Delphi.  You needed to shut the main form in order to allow the EVENT to get processed....

Comment: It doesn't even hide the main form. It just determines whether or not the main form shows when Application.Run is called.

Comment: Turned out to be a simple fix - use Abort instead of Exit. Thanks to @MarcusAdams